# Can't delete item from MongoDB is MERN app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-redux

I have some query to delete item from mongo:

```
deleteCustomer: build.mutation({
        query: (id) => ({
            url: `client/cutomers/${id}`,
            method: 'DELETE',
            body: 'id',
        }),
        providesTags: ['DeleteUser'],
    }),
```

How it looks in the controller:

```
export const deleteCustomer = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.params;
        const formattedUsers = User.findByIdAndDelete(id);
        res.status(200).json(formattedUsers);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: e.message })
    }
}
```

And how in route:

```
import express from "express";
import { getEmployees, getCustomers, getTransactions, getGeography, deleteCustomer, getCustomer } from "../controllers/client.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/employees", getEmployees);
router.get("/customers", getCustomers);
router.get("/transactions", getTransactions);
router.get("/geography", getGeography);

router.get("/customers/:id", getCustomer);
router.delete("/customers/:id", deleteCustomer);

export default router;
```

And as soon as I make a request to remove an object from the byza, I get the following error:
[image]

I have verified that the get request works correctly when using fetch.
This is how I make a request:

```
const [deleteCustomer] = useDeleteCustomerMutation()   

function handleDeleteUser(id) {
    // fetch('http://localhost:5001/client/customers/' + id, {
    //     method: 'GET',
        // })
        // .then(res => res.json())
        // .then(res => console.log(res))
        deleteCustomer(id)
    }
```

I believe that I did not correctly implement the delete function in deleteUser at the controller level. I would appreciate your advice on solving this problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the route url you are fetching. On you screenshot it seems that the route you are currently making a post request url is `http://localhost:5001/client/cutomers/...`

I think it is in the following function :

```js
deleteCustomer: build.mutation({
        query: (id) => ({
            url: `client/cutomers/${id}`, // You put cutomers instead of customers
            method: 'DELETE',
            body: 'id',
        }),
        providesTags: ['DeleteUser'],
    }),
```

That could explain why your server give a 404 not found response.

Can you try to make a correction and give us an update ?